# Is simple closed curve homeomorphic to a circle?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, plane-curves

For sure every curve that is homeomorphic to a circle is a simple closed curve, but is **every** simple closed curve homeomorphic to a circle?

Is there a proof for that, or is there some topological invariant that is not not shared with simple closed curve and a curve that is homeomorphic to a circle?

"*Simple closed curve*" = "*non-self-intersecting continuous closed curve in plane*."

Comment: What, precisely, is a continuous curve? Seems to me that your answer to this question should go most of the way to answering your main question.

Comment: I don't know and I don't care; it's enough for me if we can do all the various calculations with **arbitrary** rational precision $\epsilon >0$.

Comment: Well, you should care. As @lhf says in his response, a continuous curve is *precisely* the image of an injective *continuous* map from the circle to the plane. It all drops out from that.

Comment: Well, we can stretch and bend the continuum as much as we wish, and also remember for curve $\gamma[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$, $\gamma[0]=\gamma[1]$, that  $\gamma(x)=\gamma(y) \iff x=y$. "What is the _continuum_?" is a fundamental question and I don't have the answer - I take the pragmatic approach.

Comment: Imagine person A asks a question: *For sure every prime number is a primordial number but is every primordial number a prime?* Then you ask them in the comments: *what do you actually mean by a primordial number?* and they reply: *I don't know and I don't care, it's enough for me that we know how to add and multiply them*. Would you be able to help that person? My point is, nobody here will ask you for the precise definition just to split hairs. They are trying to find out what you're actually asking and it's impossible if you refuse to define the terms you're using to pose the question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

"*non-self-intersecting continuous closed curve in plane*" is the same as "*image of a continuous injective function from the circle to the plane*".

Since the circle is compact, such a function has a continuous inverse and so is a homeomorphism between the circle and the curve.

Comment: OK. Now I belive in Jordan curve theorem.

Comment: @John: Note that this is very far from being a proof of the Jordan curve theorem.

Comment: Well of course, but now it's clear to me that Jordan curve theorem deals both Jordan curves and simple closed curves (that are the same as I saw).

Answer (score 0):

A non-self-intersecting continuous closed curve in the plane should be equivalent to a circle at least topologically however still bounded to the plane there are curves that are not circles which may not be smoothly transformed into a circle furthermore a circle is not equivalent to itself turned inside out if you distinguish between the inside and the outside. Whether or not two curves bounded to an euclidean plane are the same can be determined by counting the total number of signed revolutions about the curve circle=1 inside out circle=-1 for more information see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R_w4HYXuo9M