# Closed curve in a torus diffeomorphic to a circle?

Tags: manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, quotient-spaces, diffeomorphism

In Example 15.9 of Tu's "An Introduction to Manifolds: Second Edition", it is written

> Let G be the torus $R^2/Z^2$ and L a line through the origin in R2. The torus can also be represented by the unit square with the opposite edges identified. The image H of L under the projection π : $R^2$ → $R^2/Z^2$ is a closed curve if and only if the line L goes through another lattice point, say (m,n) ∈ $Z^2$. This is the case if and only if the slope of L is n/m, a rational number or ∞; then H is the image of finitely many line segments on the unit square. It is a closed curve diffeomorphic to a circle and is a regular submanifold of $R^2/Z^2$

Intuitively, it is understandable the closed curve mentioned above is diffeomorphic to a circle. I also read several related questions like [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1132735/is-simple-closed-curve-homeomorphic-to-a-circle) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1968039/show-that-n-torus-is-diffeomorphic-to-the-product-of-n-circles) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4016171/example-15-9-in-loring-tus-an-introduction-to-manifolds), and understood this closed curve is homeomorphic to a circle, however, I can't prove the smoothness rigorously.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: The map from $L$ to its image is a local diffeomorphism.

Comment: Can you describe the smooth structure on $\mathbb R^2/\mathbb Z^2$? Do you know that the quotient map is smooth and a local diffeomorphism?